# In C, is an array of characters always and only ever used to represent a string?

Tags: c

Since realizing that a string data type in `C` is actually an array of `char` data type with a `NULL` byte as a terminator...

What else could an array of `char`s be used for other than as a string? In the `C` language, is there anything that an array of chars is used for that ISN'T a string?

Comment: Just as an array of signed/unsigned bytes

Comment: They're commonly used to store raw binary data read from a file or received over serial etc before it is processed.

Comment: @AlexLop.- why does signed/unsigned matter in the context of `char[]`? (I would have thought that would only matter with `int` / non-text related things)

Comment: It affects the range of values you can store. If it's signed, it stores numbers from -128 to 127. If it's unsigned, it stores numbers from 0 to 255.

Comment: `char` is just a single byte integer in C.

Comment: @Barmar - can a byte contain anything other than an integer? does `char[]` then mean an array of items comprised of 8 bits? This seems confusing since `char`, as far as I'm aware is very specifically a shorthand way of writing 'character' which implies text

Comment: @ZachSmith C has 3 char types, they are ”char”, ”signed char” and ”unsigned char”. ”char” should only be used when representing ascii charatcers and can be either signed or unsigned, it’s enviroment specific. ”signed char” and ”unsigned char” are 8 bit signed/unsigned datatype which should be used when you want just that, 8 bits to store numbers.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, a `char` is *at least* 8 bits wide - it may be wider on some platforms.  It’s large enough to store the encodings of characters from the basic execution character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char` is just a small integer in C. It's frequently used for printable characters, and that's how it's used when you use a `char` array as a string.

But a `char` array can be used whenever you need an array of bytes. A common use is when reading binary data from files or the network. Since the signedness of `char` is implementation-dependent, you should generally be more specific, either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

Modern versions of the C standard have added typedefs `uint8_t` and `int8_t`, for unsigned and signed 8-bit integer types.

Comment: Thank you - seems like `char` is badly named then... why not just have `byte[]`? Then there would be one less datatype to work with

Comment: Because the most frequent use is to hold characters. We now have typedefs like `uint8_t` for bytes.

Comment: Short for unsigned int 8bit type.

Comment: for those purposes usually signed char or unsigned char is used. Cause C standard does not define signess of char type

Comment: @Alex not usually, should always use signed/unsigned char then when not using char for characters.

Comment: I am trying to be polite